# Java - Error:(106, 106) java: cannot find symbol symbol: variable valueOf location: class net.minecraft.world.end.DragonFightManager<C>

Tags: java, minecraft

We have a school project to make a mod for the popular video game Minecraft. I decided to make my own version of the 1.9.4 client. When I decompile it and put into an intelliJ project a few errors come. Most of them are easy to find out and can be fixed by reimporting a few files, but 1 stayed behind. The error was a single line of code in the `DragonFightManager Class`. Code was: `this.gateways.addAll((Collection<? extends Integer>) ContiguousSet.create(Range.<C>closedOpen(valueOf, 20, DiscreteDomain.integers())));`. When I hit run/decompile the error:  `Error:(106, 106) java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   variable valueOf   location: class net.minecraft.world.end.DragonFightManager<C>`, comes. I did a bit of research and find that the "Cannot Find Symbol" error means I haven't used the variable correctly, in this case the `valueOf` variable. I thought maybe it was an import that I am missing so here are all the imports

```
import java.io.*;
import com.google.common.collect.*;
import net.minecraft.block.state.BlockWorldState;
import net.minecraft.block.state.pattern.BlockMatcher;
import net.minecraft.block.state.pattern.BlockPattern;
import net.minecraft.block.state.pattern.FactoryBlockPattern;
import net.minecraft.entity.Entity;
import net.minecraft.entity.boss.EntityDragon;
import net.minecraft.entity.boss.dragon.phase.PhaseList;
import net.minecraft.entity.item.EntityEnderCrystal;
import net.minecraft.entity.player.EntityPlayerMP;
import net.minecraft.init.Blocks;
import net.minecraft.nbt.NBTTagCompound;
import net.minecraft.nbt.NBTTagInt;
import net.minecraft.nbt.NBTTagList;
import net.minecraft.nbt.NBTUtil;
import net.minecraft.tileentity.TileEntity;
import net.minecraft.tileentity.TileEntityEndPortal;
import net.minecraft.util.DamageSource;
import net.minecraft.util.EntitySelectors;
import net.minecraft.util.EnumFacing;
import net.minecraft.util.math.AxisAlignedBB;
import net.minecraft.util.math.BlockPos;
import net.minecraft.util.text.TextComponentTranslation;
import net.minecraft.world.BossInfo;
import net.minecraft.world.BossInfoServer;
import net.minecraft.world.WorldServer;
import net.minecraft.world.biome.BiomeEndDecorator;
import net.minecraft.world.chunk.Chunk;
import net.minecraft.world.gen.feature.WorldGenEndGateway;
import net.minecraft.world.gen.feature.WorldGenEndPodium;
import net.minecraft.world.gen.feature.WorldGenSpikes;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

import javax.annotation.Nullable;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

import static java.lang.Integer.*;
```

So what is the fix to this error and if you need more detail please say so in the comments.

***EXTRA INFO*****
[Tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_valueof.htm) I used for the valueOf. And for some reason when I import java.io.*; it doesn't have a color like any of the other imports, so maybe that's it. Idk:/

Comment: Oh I found the answer,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error means that you're using a variable (`valueOf`) that has never been declared nor initialized.

Maybe there was a problem while decompiling, [but I googled it](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=sudofox/Backmemed/Backmemed-master/minecraft/net/minecraft/world/end/DragonFightManager.java) and instead of `valueOf` there should be written `Integer.valueOf(0)`

Comment: Ok I will see if that works

Comment: Ok the error is passed but this happens Error: Could not find or load main class =
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: =

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Where are you getting this error? Is there a line number and/or some example you can provide?

Comment: Oh I think it is for the whole project because I googled it and found I have to change the build path. The thing is I am on ItelliJ not eclipse so I am trying :/

Comment: So have you found a way to get past this or no?

Comment: How would I find a way? The only thing I see is that the JVM sees a = symbol as a class name, but I have not any code to inspect, so it's a bit hard to solve it

Comment: The code has 0 errors it is the classpath that isn't resolved